# SQL Server CE System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, exception, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

[image]

How to handle such an error, even though we have written general exception in catch?

Comment: Please show the query.

Comment: query method which is declared in the global where we access it thorugh all VM to get data from SqlCE Database before getting call to this method it executes two query method which executes & which does not give me such error but when it executed 3rd query it gives me a error  for Your reference i copied a query call   var SampList=repositoryBO.SamplingPlanBO.Query(x => x.CompanyID == this.Company.CompanyID && x.ValidFromYear >= Constant.ConstantValues.CurrentDateTime.Year && x.IsDeleted == false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using the same DbContext across threads, and that is not supported, as DbContext and SqlCeConnection are not thread safe

Comment: Yes @ErikEJ   but  how can i resolve it as of now because which is causing me a very big issue  as it cause directly crash on client machine  i try to execute only query method in different thread to get out of it but it is still continue executing the same